# Is there a way to undo # kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/mysqld.pid`?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

So I was trying to reset my MySQL password on my Raspberry Pi and it seems that my database crashed or is now inaccessible.

I was following the section called, [“B.5.3.2.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix) of the official MySQL documentation.

As soon as I ran:

```
kill `cat /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`
```

Then input:

```
# sudo service mysqld restart
```

I’d get:

```
# mysqld: unrecognized service
```

I hope that I didn’t just nuke my entire database. Can someone help?

Comment: The service is called `mysql`, not mysqld

Answer (score 1):

You are following generic MySQL instructions for a Linux setup when you are on a Raspberry Pi using [Raspbian](https://www.raspbian.org) (I assume).

All that message means is the service named `mysqld` is unrecognized by your system. It does not mean it has crashed or data was lost. It just means your OS doesn’t know what `mysqld` is as far as services go. That’s it; nothing to panic about.

A quick Google search shows that [Raspbian uses a different system service name simply known as `mysql`](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/software_utilities/mysql). So to start it up again just run this command:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

And you should be good to go. Also note that whole command you ran to stop the service is overkill:

```
kill `cat /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`
```

Running a `kill` command like that should only happen when all other options are exhausted and you truly want to stop the database server. The way you should be stopping, starting and generally controlling the MySQL server is via the `service` interface using a command like this:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

And if you wanted to restart the service, just run this command:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Past any of that if you are stuck with an “unrecognized service” message, then you can always check the stuff in the `/etc/init.d` directory on your Linux machine like this:

```
ls -la /etc/init.d/
```

Look through that list and find the exact name of the service you need to do something with and then just run the `service` command as outlined above.

Comment: Wow. Mysql is running just fine. I can log on. I can see my things through winscp. 

I have no idea what's causing: "Error establishing a database connection"

Comment: OH jeeesus. I just realized that I changed the database pw so I had to match that with the wp-config.php that had the old pw...